# Do the Xbox One games erase if I disconnect the console from the power?

Tags: xbox-one

I am moving and I was wondering if my games will erase if I disconnect the Xbox One console.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Just to be clear, what do you mean by "erase"? Are you asking if you can still play the games when you hook it back up?

Answer (score 6):

Unless you have modified your console to replace its built-in HDD with some sort of RAM disk, removing power won't affect the data stored inside, even over extended period of time.

However, if a game is currently *running* and you *haven't* saved your progress before removing power, that progress will be lost. Already saved progress will remain safe.

---

#### Important

Keep in mind that it's best to unplug your Xbox One while it's powered off to avoid damage to your disk. If your Xbox One is installing something, like a system update, unplugging it then can render it useless.

**Make doubly sure** that your console is in **Power Saving Mode** before turning it off to avoid entering standby, and **only then** remove the power cord.

Answer (score 0):

No. Saved content is stored on a hard drive or USB flash device (thumb drive). Neither require power to keep stored data when the system is off.

Comment: However, if the data is being written at the time, it will potentially render the drive unreadable; So this is slightly mis-leading

Comment: @Timelord64 Not misleading... perhaps assuming too much of the OP, though. Adjusted.